Hibernate 5.3.3 limitation in clause after upgrade
i just upgrade from hibernate 5.2 to 5.3 but i have a problem in my queries, i have multiple queries that have multiple params in  the in clause which cause a stackoverflow error with this lines repeated, do someone know how to resolve this problem ?
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.StringHelper.replace(StringHelper.java:128)

upgrading to 5.4 doesn't show this error anymore but i'm getting multiple other errors, i try just to work with 5.3 for now because it's the version that contain only this error.
i'm using spring boot 2.7.18 with hibernate 5.3.x

probably more context needed - like a full stack trace. What database version? Was this upgraded at the same time?

i'm using mysql 5.6 but the problem occurs also in mysql 8, the full stack trace is only a repeated at org.hibernate.internal.util.StringHelper.replace(StringHelper.java:128) caused by my in clause that contains thousand of params. but this problem doesn't occur in version 5.4 but i can't use 5.4 for now.

i couldn't find where it comes from, i just upgrade to 5.4 and the problem was resolved
